# How can I upgrade KDE in Kubuntu 11.10

Tags: 11.10, upgrade, kubuntu, kde

How can I upgrade KDE 4.7.4 to KDE 4.8 in Kubuntu 11.10? Is it safe to upgrade or should i wait for Kubuntu 12.04.

Comment: The Kubuntu.org has the release announcement and with it the "how to update/upgrade": http://www.kubuntu.org/news/kde-sc-4.8.0 . The "safeness" will depend of you and your system. The tales of joy and sorrow can be found from the http://www.kubuntuforums.net/ and http://ubuntuforums.org/ .

Answer (score 3):

Upgrading to kde4.8 is your choice  .If you really want to upgrade kde ,follow these steps

**KDE 4.8 FOR UBUNTU 11.10**

*Step 1* - Add KDE SC 4.8 repositories

Hit the CTRL+ALT+T key combination on your keyboard and paste the following command in the terminal window:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:kubuntu-ppa/backports
```

Enter your password when asked and hit the Enter key.

Then paste the following command in the terminal window:

```
sudo apt-get update
```

Close the terminal window when the operation is done! Proceed to the next step.

Step 2 - Install KDE SC 4.8

All you need to do now is to click the [link](http://apt://kubuntu-desktop)

[image]

Click here to Install KDE SC 4.8

Wait a few seconds, and the Ubuntu Software Center application will appear. Click the "Install" button on the new window...

To install the KDE SC 4.8.0 packages enter your password when asked...
[image]

Wait for the KDE SC 4.8 packages to be downloaded and installed...

...when the installation is over close Ubuntu Software Center and reboot your computer.

When you get back, at the login screen, select your username, click the Sessions button and select the KDE Plasma Workspace entry.
[image]

**Install KDE 4.8 in Kubuntu 11.10 Oneiric Ocelot**

If you've installed Icon Tasks via PPA, remove it before upgrading (sudo apt-get remove plasma-widget-icon-tasks) or else you'll get an error.

The Kubuntu developers have done a great job as usual, and the latest KDE 4.8 is already available in the official Kubuntu Backports PPA, for Kubuntu 11.10 Oneiric Ocelot. Add the PPA and upgrade to KDE 4.8 using the commands below:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:kubuntu-ppa/backports
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

Oxygen GTK3 Engine has not been packaged yet unfortunately, but you can use THIS PPA (not tested) to install it. But please note that using it, you'll also get some other unstable packages.

**Uninstalling KDE SC 4.8 (optional)**

If you want to remove KDE SC 4.8 from your system, or downgrade to the previously installed version, all you have to do is to hit the CTRL+ALT+T key combination on your keyboard and paste the following commands in the terminal window (one by one, hitting Enter after each one):

```
sudo apt-get install -y ppa-purge
sudo ppa-purge ppa:kubuntu-ppa/backports
sudo apt-get -f -y autoremove
```

[SOURCE](http://news.softpedia.com/news/How-to-Install-KDE-SC-4-8-on-Ubuntu-11-10-248829.shtml)

Comment: I am using Kubuntu 11.10 so when I clicked that link it came Kubuntu-desktop is already installed. The thing is that I want to upgrade my KDE shell from 4.7.4 to version 4.8.

Comment: kubuntu included