# Installing the normal Kubuntu-Desktop after removing the Version from PPA

Tags: kubuntu

I installed this KDE Version with the commands from this [link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/108427/how-can-i-upgrade-kde-in-kubuntu-11-10)  (on my Kubuntu 11.10) and after that i removed it with your commands because it freezes all the time.

But when i log in in Kunbutu it is always this version.

I tried with purge kubuntu* to remove all Kubuntu Pieces, but when after that I install kubuntu-desktop again it is again the newest ppa Version.

Can you help me to return to then normal Kubuntu-Desktop? When i will install it with synpatic, i always find only the version from ppa, but i removed ppa sources!

Thank you

Karin

Answer (score 0):

Should do it:

```
sudo ppa-purge ppa:kubuntu-ppa/backports
```

As opposed to just pulling out kubuntu*, it also would pull out any dependency stuff that might have also come from that ppa(for example an odd-ball version of Qt), and force reversion to packages from standard repo.

It should ideally have been run before you tried to remove kubuntu*.

Comment: Could you explain what the commend does, and any necessary prerequisites?